# Refresh a page only once php

Tags: php, refresh

I am using PHP for my website and clicked from say myfile.php I want the page to be refreshed only once:
The code would be like:

```
<?php 
 if(called from myfile.php){
 header(refresh:0);
 }
Php code 1;
PHP code 2;
.
.
.
PHP code n;
?>
```

How to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but I think you will need something similar to this:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET["caller"] ) && $_GET["caller"] == "somevalue" ) {
    // I'm using Location because this will remove the get value
    header( "Location: index.php" );
    exit;
}
?>
<a href="index.php">just go to index</a><br/>
<a href="index.php?caller=somevalue">got to index and refresh?</a>
```

I just used *index.php* for testing.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
if(empty($_GET['status'])){
     header('Location:YourPagesPath.php?status=1');
     exit;
}
```

Which would reload the page and if the `GET` parameter isn't present.

Comment: (empty($_GET['status'])) didnt work for me as I have to pass different values to that variable.

Comment: You can pass different values and not use `empty` that was just a simple example. Looks like you go this working already though, no?

Answer (score 1):

In `myfile.php` set a session variable

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['calledFrom'] = 'myfile.php';
```

and check for it in this file

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['calledFrom'])) && 'myfile.php' == $_SESSION['calledFrom']) {
    $_SESSION['calledFrom'] = 'thisfile.php';
    header("Refresh:0");
} else {
    $_SESSION['calledFrom'] = 'thisfile.php';
}
```

Comment: I dont want to keep the session variable set all the time otherwise it will do it everytime after session variable is set.

Comment: That's what the second condition (`'myfile.php' == $_SESSION['calledFrom']`) is for.